# Which ORM to use for Python and MySql?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, pyqt

So I have a database that stores a lot of information about many different objects; to simplify it, just imagine a database that stores information about the weights of 100 dogs and 100 cats over a period of a few years. I made a GUI, and I want one of the tabs to allow the user to enter a newly taken weight or change the past weight of a pet if it was wrong.

I created the GUI using Qt Designer. Before, I communicated with the database using SqlAlchemy. However, PyQt4 also offers QtSql, which I think is another ORM? Could someone explain to me how the ORM exactly works, and what the difference is between SqlAlchemy, QtSql, and even Sql Connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Qt Sql** is the SQL Framework that comes with Qt library. It provides basic (and classic) classes to access a database, execute queries and fetch the results.*Qt can be recompiled to support various DBMS such as MySQL, Postgres etc.

**Sql Connector**
I assume you refer to MySql Connector ?
If so, it's a set of C++ classes to access natively a MySql database.
Classes are almost the same than those in QtSQL. But you don't have to support the Wrapper layer of Qt. But of course, you cannot access another database than MySQL.

**Sql Alchemy**
It's hard to briefly explain the complexity of an ORM.
Object Relation Mapping. Wikipedia says:

> "A technique for converting data between incompatible type systems in
>   object-oriented programming languages"

It's a good definition. It's basically a technique to map table / queries data into Object-Oriented data structure.

For example, an ORM engine hides the process that explicitly maps the fields of a TABLE to an OO class.
In addition, it works the same whatever the database you're accessing (as long as the ORM knows the DBMS dialect).

For such a purpose, Python language and philosophy perfectly fits an ORM. 
But an ORM such as SqlAlchemy is everything but an Object-Oriented Database !

It has some limitations though.
If you need to make complex queries (and believe me, it often happens in specific contexts), it becomes a bit tricky to use it properly and you might experience performance penalties.

If you need just need to access a single table with hundreds records...it won't be worth it as the initialization process is a bit laborious.

Z.